# Embed power BI Report into an website using MVC

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am new to Power BI API and following the below link to embed a power BI report in an website that uses a .NETSDK.

[embed sample for customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers#workspace-id)

I am an Azure active directory user and I have downloaded power BI using my active directory account. I followed [embedding setup tool](https://aka.ms/embedsetup/AppOwnsData) to setup an application as Native user and get the application id to be used for API calls. One of my team member designed a power BI report and published the workspace sharing with me. My AuthenticationType is MasterUser.
I downloaded the sample application available in GitHub as mentioned in the above tutorial. I have been made an admin for my power BI pro account and trying to integrate the report in the website. I replaced the credentials and other ids as as described in the tutorial. But this gives me the following error-

unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type

This is the piece of code that's failing during AquireTokenAsync call.

```
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> DoAuthentication()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        if (AuthenticationType.Equals("MasterUser"))
        {
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);

            // Authentication using master user credentials
            var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
            authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ApplicationId, credential).Result;
        }

        return authenticationResult;
    }
```

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I am using the sample application available at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples

Comment: @Greg I have added the piece of code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Display-Power-BI-reports-in-website-for-non-Power-BI-users/td-p/218541), you must be an admin of the workspace you are trying to embed. Using a AAD user that is only a member of the workspace for embedding will cause this error.

Comment: My account is an admin account. Is there a difference between having an admin account and being admin of a specific workspace. My understanding is if I am an admin of the account, I am an admin of all workspaces available or shared. Let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: In this case there is a difference. In the embedded docs it notes that "In either scenario, both the master account or service principal must be an admin of the app workspaces involved with your application."


Please let me know if this does not work once you have been made a workspace admin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers

Comment: I verified that I am an admin of the workspace I am trying to access. I still get the same error.